# pip install django error on windows 7

Tags: python, django, windows-7

Tried installing django on my Windows 7 with Python version 3.4.3 using command line(Run as Administrator) with command:

```
pip install django
```

Here is the error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install django
Collecting django
  Using cached Django-1.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: django
  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 246, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 352, in r
un
      root=options.root_path,
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 693, in instal
l
      **kwargs
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 817, in in
stall
      self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1018, in m
ove_wheel_files
      isolated=self.isolated,
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 237, in move_wheel_f
iles
      clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 215, in clobber
      shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 108, in copyfile
      with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Loc
al\\Temp\\pip-build-5dmxxqdw\\django\\django\\core\\checks\\security\\base.py'
```

Please help.

Comment: Try to download it and easy_install it.

Comment: Are you actually the administrator on this machine? Or is a machine on a work domain?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure of it @Leon . I even tried using the Administrator account to install Django but still produced this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder C:\Python34 was set as Read-only. I changed the property and it install successfully.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by renaming the C:\Python27 folder to some random name and then back to C:\Python27 and running the command again.

Answer (score -1):

i solved this problem by opening command prompt as administrator and running the 'pip install Django' command